# Progress Message Error after processing of photoscene is complete

Tags: swift, rest, http, autodesk-forge

The Status code is 200, but I am getting an error in progressmsg. Could somebody let me know where I might be going wrong. I have uploaded 125 images and have declared the scene type as Object.

```
{

    Photoscene =     {

        photosceneid = c5bt9tAcnj1iSXjyNPhIdOGT9ZioPEE1rXwLjpgpCZ0;

        progress = 100;

        progressmsg = ERROR;

    };

    Resource = "/photoscene/c5bt9tAcnj1iSXjyNPhIdOGT9ZioPEE1rXwLjpgpCZ0/progress";

    Usage = "0.50895810127258";

}
```

Comment: Look up error code = 200.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the proprieties of that photoscene, especially to see if all the files were uploaded successfully.
To check the photoscene property, use this undocumented endpoint:

> GET
>   https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/:photosceneid/properties

For more info on this, check the following blogpost: [The Hitchhiker's Guide to ... Reality Capture API](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api).